# php preg_match_all problems

Tags: php, image, preg-match-all

I would like to filter the images by checking its extension, and my coding is as below:

```
preg_match_all("/<img.*?src=\"(.*?)\".*?\/>/i", $this->content, $resultImg);
```

and the result will be like this:

```
Array (
     [0] => xxx/logo.png?1253 
     [1] => xxx/banner.jpg?1253 
     [2] => xxx/6606072563_a9d41ef0ca_z_medium.jpeg?1253 
     [3] => xxx/6605789711_43e2ca1f0d_z_medium.bmp?1253 
)
```

But the system just accept jpg, png & gif, may I know how can I remove the image URL which extension is not jpg, png & gif by using the coding above?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the attribute you should play with the | operator in regexp.
Here is an ugly regex that could do the job:

```
/<img.*?(((class=\"([a-z0-9 ]+)\")|(style=\"([a-z0-9 :;#\-]+)\")|(name=\"([a-z0-9]+)\")|(id=\"([a-z0-9]+)\")|(src=\"(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(\?[0-9]*)?\")).*?)+\/>/i
```

I used the following code to test it:

```
<img style="margin-left:20px;color:#fff;" onclick="javascript::void()"  class="xxx" id="4" src="test.gif?12345" name="anam" />
```

If you try to parse html syntax you should use things like [htmlsimpledom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), that will be less hard to understand and implement

Comment: but I am still facing the same problem if I using simple_html_dom, how can I filter .bmp file?

Comment: I get it~foreach($html->find('img[src$=.jpg],img[src$=.jpeg],img[src$=.gif],img[src$=.png]') as $element) {
  echo $element->src . '<br>';
 }

Answer (score 0):

This following regex will return matches if the extension is png jpg or gif only

```
/<img.*?src=\"(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)\".*?\/>/i
```

Edit to take care of you digit parameter

```
/<img.*?src=\"(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(\?[0-9]*)?\".*?\/>/i
```

You should improve by accpeting the ' char as wrapper of the address (src argument of img tag)
I'm curious, so can you explain me why you use the lasy start (*?) operator? I never used it so don't know in which use case it is helpfull.

Regards

Comment: Hi grifos, thanks for your reply, it is workable if there is not any words behind the extension, e.g.: aaa.jpg. but if the image file consists of extra words behind its extension like aaa.jpg?12345, then it can't get the images...

Comment: Sorry forgot to take care of you parameters, i will update my answer

Comment: Hi grifos, thanks for your speedy reply, it is working perfectly. Good job:)

Comment: Hi grifos, one more question, if there is some words between img & src, like <img class='xxx' style='xx' src='xxx'>, how can we detect it?